# How many parameters are being optimised over in a simple CNN?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

Okay so here's my CNN (simple example from a tutorial) along with some arithmetic to get the total number of free parameters.

We've got a dataset of 28*28 grayscale image (MNIST).

1. First layer is a 2D convolution using 32 3x3 kernels. Dimensionality of the output is 26x26x32 (kernel stride length was 1 and we have 32 feature maps of 26x26). **Running parameter count: 288**
2. Second layer is 2x2 MaxPool with a 2x2. Dimensionality of the output is 13x13x32 but then we flatten so we got a vector of length 5408. No extra parameters here.
3. Third layer is Dense. A 5408x100 matrix. Dimensionality of the output is 100. **Running Parameter count: 540988**
4. Fourth layer is Dense also. A 100x10 matrix. Dimensionality of the output is 10. **Running Parameter count: 541988**

Then we're supposed to do stochastic gradient descent on a 541988 parameter space!

That feels like a ridiculously big number to me. And this is meant to be the hello world problem of CNNs. Am I missing something fundamental in my understanding of how this is meant to work? Or maybe the number is correct but it's not actually a big deal for a computer to crunch?

In case it helps. Here is how the model was built in Keras:

```
def define_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metric=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Comment: Neural networks have a lot of parameters. Usually the last Conv layers before Dense are a bit smaller to reduce the total number of parameters. But it is also normal for neural networks to have more parameters than points.

Comment: @keiv.fly thanks. But how does adding more conv layers help decrease the parameters? Isn't that just *increasing* the parameters to optimise over? All you're doing is decreasing the parameter space of the ouput signal, but increasing the parameter space of the optimisation problem. Or to really explain how I'm thinking here: you added another conv layer, so you added more kernels, and now we need to also figure out what the optimal shapes of all these extra kernels are.

Comment: Its not a big deal, we have neural network with tens to hundreds million parameters and we can train them with SGD just fine.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks! So does that mean my arithmetic and understanding are correct in calculating the number 541988?

Comment: Yeah it looks correct, you can confirm by calling model.count_params()

Comment: According to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf the first conv layer has 56x56x64 nodes and the last one has 7x7x512 nodes. Then the averaging layer makes 512 nodes and only then is the dense layer (there called fc) is applied